# Extract the rotation (or heading) from local matrix (Blender Python)

Tags: matrix

If I use physics then the objects rotation not changed but I want to detect the object rotation based an another empty axes (or the world mtrix).

I tried extract rotation attribs from local matrix but I stucked.
Are there a built in function for extract the actual rotation values of the objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Quaternion.rotation_difference(...)`**

Can represent the matrix world of both your objects as a quaternion. Its `rotation_difference(...)` method returns a quaternion describing the rotation required to go from one alignment to the other.

Test script, select objects, then axis last so it will be active object. Script below prints the XYZ Euler rotation required by axis  to match object.

```
import bpy
from math import degrees

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
others = context.selected_objects
others.remove(ob)
axis = ob.matrix_world.to_quaternion()
for o in others:
    q = o.matrix_world.to_quaternion()
    rotdif = axis.rotation_difference(q)
    print(o.name, tuple(degrees(a) for a in rotdif.to_euler()))
```

Result of running on default file with "Camera" as axis object.

```
Cube (-54.05801712949699, -40.65919063845337, -25.28499489226661)
Lamp (-10.627706900421787, 53.1995955395152, 34.18299651274404)
```